# Harmon.Ie Sidebar in outlook is blank after most recent update

Tags: harmon.ie

The Harmon.id sidebar in outlook is blank after latest update.   I am using the Free tool.

Comment: Can you add some more detail? Are you using the current Outlook version? Can you post a screenshot in case there's a small hint about what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Outlook settings, choose "Optimize for compatibility" option, restart Outlook

----- Jean